# ExtJS 5.x : Edit a grid cell with popup

Tags: extjs5, tablecelleditor

Can a popup window (with a form) be opened for a cell in extjs grid to edit and save it to database?

This shouldn't directly update the database, but it should go through the grid data model for updating the database.

Note: Data grid also has in-place editing feature enabled and is working well.

```
    listeners: {
        'celldblclick' : function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
            var clickedDataIndex = view.panel.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(cellIndex).dataIndex;
            var clickedColumnName = view.panel.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(cellIndex).text;
            var clickedCellValue = record.get(clickedDataIndex);
            var comment_form = new Ext.form.Panel({
                baseCls: 'x-plain',
                labelWidth: 155,
                //width: 600,
                autoHeight: true,
                defaultType: 'textarea',
                jsonSubmit: true,
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Add Comment',
                    name: 'comment',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%',
                }],
            });

            var newPanel = new Ext.Panel ({
                border: false,
                html: "<br />" + clickedCellValue + "<br />",
                autoHeight: true,
            });

            var win = new Ext.Window({
                title: clickedColumnName,
                width: 500,
                autoHeight: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                plain: true,
                bodyStyle: 'padding:5px;',
                buttonAlign: 'center',
                items: form,
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Update',
                    //disabled: true,
                }, {
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler:function() {
                        form.getForm().reset();
                    }
                }]
            });

            form.add(newPanel);
            win.show();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Yes it can. I did it on the last column of a grid: a double-clic opened a window in which the user could change the data of the same store than the one for the grid. The `autoSync` property of this store did the rest automatically. ExtJS is wonderful!

Comment: @Michael, Could you please help me with the code snippet for the same - ?
I've autoSync enabled in my store and the update is not transferred to the DB.

Comment: If you could make a working example in a fiddle, it would be nice and easier for me to help you